# Description and additional Info Tabs showing twice

Tags: product

I am new to Magento, took the leap from Zencart following lack of support
I have purchased a theme from an online template supplier, who I then had to pay more money to to get it to install properly (Instructions were inadequate)
However I am still having problems, but the theme supplier is ignoring support requests (Unless I pay more money)
When you view any of my product, there is two rows of Product Desciption, Additional Info and Product Review Tabs. It would appear to be both the "Default ones AND the Theme based ones at the same time
Can anyone point me to either where I turn it off in Admin or where I need to alter the code to get it to work properly.
Needless to say it wasn't like this on the Demo site

Example page (I must warn you, it is an adult toy store)
http://specialcuddles.com/catalog/product/view/id/1234/

Hope somebody can help

Regards

Comment: Hi Mike and welcome to MageOverflow. Unfortunately third party themes are out of the scope of this website. Because this question has an answer I don't vote to close. But in case it get closed and people don't write a comment :-)

Comment: Hi. I appreciate that specific themes cannot be supported, just a bit of a clue as to where the error may be is a big help. I self taught with Zencart and I will do the same with Magento, just trying to get my head around where things are

Comment: I would just like to add that this question was not too broad at all, it was very specific, based on a very specific problem, which somebody had the time to give me some very specific answers to, which has solved the problem. So Thanks Jason for helping, and no thanks to all the "Voters" who couldn't be bothered, other than to interfere. Vote away, close it, delete it, I'm not bothered, Jason has made the time to detail some pointers which has solved the problem and has given me enough clues to possible answer some questions I may have in the future without having to come back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like the XML for name="product.attributes" may be getting added twice. Since Magento globs the XML this could technically be in any XML file but there are two places where you should check first.

> app/design/frontend/YOUR_PACKAGE/YOUR_THEME/layout/local.xml

and if not there then:

> app/design/frontened/YOUR_PACKAGE/YOUR_THEME/layout/catalog.xml

The code that adds the tabs block is:

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_attributes" name="product.attributes" as="additional" template="catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml">
  <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
</block>
```

See if this is being duplicated and remove the duplicate.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi Thanks for the prompt reply. I cannot find the exact files. My file tree is app/design/frontend/default/MY_THEME/layout/local and catalog.xml. However I cannot find any of the code you mentioned in either file. Not certain whether I simply don't have the correct files or what????. I will keep digging, just the indication of where to start looking and what to look for is a big help. Many Thanks

Comment: Try using the template and block name hints. In the admin go to System -> Configuration - Developer (left side tab near the bottom) -> change the scope drop down to your website scope -> Debug tab - set Template Path Hints and Add Block Names to Hints both to 'Yes'.  Save and then refresh your frontend.  You should see red outlines showing you where each section pulls its templates (.phtml files) and block names (xml files) from.

Comment: Brilliant, now sorted, thanks for the pointer Jason. Found the file, just tried to rename it to tabs_old.phtml and it worked, just got the ones that are themed and I can control these from admin